# convert HTML code to Javascript variable (string)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actually I have a strange requirement. Here I have HTML code and I have to pass this code into document.write function. To achieve that I should make that code into javascript variable and pass that code to document.write.
Let me explain it with an example.
Say if we have the below HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the equivalent JavaScript variable is as follows

```
var myVariable = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Page Title<\/title>\n<\/head>\n<body>\n\n<h1>This is a Heading<\/h1>\n<p>This is a paragraph.<\/p>\n\n<\/body>\n<\/html>\n';
```

So that we can use this variable in document.write function as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
    var myVariable = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Page Title<\/title>\n<\/head>\n<body>\n\n<h1>This is a Heading<\/h1>\n<p>This is a paragraph.<\/p>\n\n<\/body>\n<\/html>\n';
document.write(myVariable);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Indeed, to get the JavaScript variable I am using on-line conversion [tool](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/syntax/prepareInline.html). But, I decided to convert my HTML code to sting manually. So I would like to know how we can do it in JavaScript or any other language. Actually I am a Ruby on Rails developer so I wonder that there is an easy way to do it manually in ruby.

Comment: Define "not working as expected"

Comment: Modified Please check it once

Comment: Now not sure what the question is. HTML _is_ a string (textual data, at least).

Comment: have to make it as JS object

Comment: So, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Can't go every-time to that tool to get JS varibale

Comment: So you want a function which converts HTML into JS-encoded output?

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**   Remove the line breaks, making the entire string a single line

```
var lines = '<div id="jwplayer"><center>...</center></div>';
document.write(lines);
```

**Method 2** Escape the line breaks with backslashes.

```
var lines = '<div id="jwplayer">\
    <center>\
      ...\
    </center>\
  </div>';
document.write(lines);
```

**Method 3**: Concatenate the string a line at a time

```
var lines = '<div id="jwplayer">';
lines += '<center>';
lines += '...';
lines += '</center>';
lines += '</div>';
document.write(lines);
```

**Method 4 :** Create an array strings and join them

```
var lines = [
  '<div id="jwplayer">',
  '<center>',
  '...',
  '</center>',
  '</div>'].join(' ');
document.write(lines);
```

Source : [Javascript document.write('HTML CODE HERE') and using a var grabbed by flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810454/javascript-document-writehtml-code-here-and-using-a-var-grabbed-by-flash)

Answer (score 4):

This will take the input from a textarea and create the variable code.  It escapes backslashes and quotes as needed:

```
function makeVariable() {
  var code= document.getElementById('input').value.trim(),
      output= document.getElementById('output');

  output.textContent= 'var myVariable= "'+
                      code.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
                          .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
                          .replace(/[\n\r]/g, '\\n')+
                      '";';
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', makeVariable);

function makeVariable() {
  var code= document.getElementById('input').value.trim(),
      output= document.getElementById('output');
  
  output.textContent= 'var myVariable= "'+
                      code.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
                          .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
                          .replace(/[\n\r]/g, '\\n')+
                      '";';
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 20em;
  width: 100%;
}

pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: #246;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<button>Create variable</button>

<pre id="output"></pre>

<textarea id="input">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 class="header">This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This has a backslash \.</p>

</body>
</html>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right in assuming you want to generate "encoded" HTML through JS, this [resource seems to answer the question](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/html/encode.html):

```
function OuterHTML(element) {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
  return container.innerHTML;
}

function encodeMyHtml(html) {
 encodedHtml = escape(html);
 encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/\//g,"%2F");
 encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/\?/g,"%3F");
 encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/=/g,"%3D");
 encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/&/g,"%26");
 encodedHtml = encodedHtml.replace(/@/g,"%40");
 return encodedHtml;
}
```

So you'd be able to call ([referencing this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript)):

```
div = document.getElementById('jwplayer');
encoded = encodeMyHtml(div);
```

Here's a JSFiddle for you: [http://jsfiddle.net/m8uyhz26/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/m8uyhz26/3/)

*If you want to return properly formatted HTML, use `unescape` with the returned data from `encodeMyHtml`*

---

The main issue you have is lack of context in your question. If you gave people a reason why you need to convert HTML or JS etc, you'd be able to receive better answers.

As it stands, you'll get a bunch of JS hacks explaining how to turn HTML into JS-encoded strings etc.